# how to save marital relationship in a database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, relational-database

I have to save this information in a database

Person -> is married to -> Person

Where should I save that information? What is the proper design pattern should I apply here?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can rely on a database to save your marriage ;D

Comment: 2 tables. A one to one relationship with an association table.

Comment: "Glenatron ladies and gentlemen!  He'll be here all weekend, don't forget to tip your waiters and waitresses!"

Comment: Cue Henny Youngman...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Nz5TWRRv8A

Comment: Not really an answer, but you might find this interesting reading: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/07/selecting-friends/  marriage is symmetric and irreflexive (try working that into your next domestic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can only be maried to one person: 1:1

```
-------------
- Person    -
-------------
id (key)
maried_to_id (foreign key)
```

If you can be maried to more than one person or want to keep track of previous mariages, n:n

```
-------------
- Person    -
-------------
person_id (key)

-------------
- Mariage   -
-------------
first_person_id (foreign key)
second_person_id (foreign key)
start_date
end_date
```

(also first_person_id + second_person_id + date form a unique key for mariage. You could leave out the date, but then remariages wouldnt be tracked)

Comment: The field maried_to_id should be completed in both persons? It's repeated information, but I can't left it blank in one of them because it wouldn't be true

Comment: @mauro: yes, it should be filled for both. of course you'll need some logic to make sure that this condition is verified (ie do not delete someone if the person is maried, do not mary to unexisting persons...)

Comment: You forgot EndDate !-) And, beeing a bit conservative, I would make it more precise for the name: HusbandId, SpouseId. This ways you enforce entry 1 way. But it wouldn't work with homosexual marriage.

Comment: @iDevelop: It's funny because it's true 50% of the time.

Comment: Very helpful, my only addition is that that for the above example to be a true 1:1 relationship you would need to have a UNIQUE constraint on the FK field.

Comment: You can sort the ids, always have the smaller id as the first person. That way your data isn't copied and you are pansexually enabled! Dont forget to tweak your joins though!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hypothetical schema you can use. All people are in a single table, and each person has a unique id. Marriages are in a relationship table, with foreign keys.

```
PERSONS
- ID - INTEGER, PK
- FIRSTNAME - VARCHAR(20)
- LASTNAME - VARCHAR(20)
- SEX - CHAR(1)
- ... any other fields

MARRIAGES
- PERSON1_ID - INTEGER, FK
- PERSON2_ID - INTEGER, FK
- MARRIAGE_DATE - DATE
- ANULLMENT_DATE - DATE
- ... any other fields
```

Comment: nice - except the use of the verb annullment is arbitrarily restrictive... i would go with begin_dt and end_dt and perhaps an end_reason attribute somewhere else if needed.

Comment: Good point Randy. Think widower vs divorcee

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question for teaching schema design. What seems like a simple problem can easily become quite complicated:

E.g., how to handle:
 - mariages of more than two people
 - different types of marriage (legal, religious, other)
 - concurrent marriages
 - repeat marriages
 - divorce
 - self-marriage (hey, it happend on Glee!)

The trick, if there is one, is to carefully think out all the permutations of what you are trying to model. Only then do you actually go ahead and model it.

Comment: also, it's possible you will need to store the detailed history information, but also need a performant way of getting any arbtirary person's current spouse, which may need some extra infrastructure... fun :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Following structure
Lets say table name is Person.

1. PersonId (int, Key)
2. MarriedTo (int,
   nullable)

.....

No need to create foreign key relation ship.

Comment: Foreign keys should pretty much **always** be enforced using a FK relationship

Comment: Note that the state is duplicated, as a.MarriedTo(b) should also mean b.MarriedTo(a).

Comment: yes - the complication of married_to having to  be equal in multiple rows is a normalization problem...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a "Spouse" column on the "Person" table which can be null (for the case of an unmarried person).

If married this holds the id of the other person, as is a foreign key.

A better solution would be a separate "Marriage" table that has at least three columns:

```
MarriageId
Person1Id
Person2Id
...
```

The person id's are foreign keys into the "Person" table, and you should make the combination of MarriageId, Person1Id and Person2Id unique to avoid adding a row where the people are swapped over.

Though it should be pointed out that both these models are quite basic and make assumptions about how many people can be in one marriage ;)

Comment: you should add something to indicate how to deal with/prevent having two marriage rows, with the person ids interchanged.

Comment: Can someone please explain how you could implement the point that araqnid is bringing up? Is the only way some trigger on an insert that would look at whats being stored, then look at the inverse and compare the two?

Comment: "you should make the combination of MarriageId, Person1Id and Person2Id unique to avoid adding a row where the people are swapped over."

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use for a simple lookup table- the important part is having two fields, one a foreign key for Person1's ID field the other a foreign key for Person2's ID field. Any details about the marriage ( dates, whether it is still current and so on ) would also be stored in this table.

That would facilitate people having had multiple marriages, polygamous relationships and so on. If you want a simple 1:1 relationship you could just include a foreign key reference to the spouse in the person field, but it would be considerably less flexible.