# Database design approach decision

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database which holds information about vehicles. I've got a main table named Vehicles in which I store main information such as VehicleType, FuelType and etc. however there are so many more details about each vehicle that should be considered such as features that each vehicle has like CDplayer, Sunroof and so on. The question is should I include all primary and auxiliary information in one single table considering the fact that it gets so messy with almost 70 field or it's better to just separate them into two table. Since there is a one to one relation between this two tables, is it a logical decision to make? Is it efficient considering the performance factor? 
Sorry if I couldn't make it more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't vertically partition a table unless you have [specific reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9688442/533120) to do so.

This applies even if your table has many columns. However, many columns *may* (but *don't have to*) be an indication of other problems in your design.

Comment: I read the specific reasons you provided and I noticed that my case is actually a "1:0 or 1" relationship. Does it make splitting a logical course of action to take? Or still there are factors to be considered?

Comment: @Metti Yes, for "1:0..1" you should probably split to two tables. The other possibility is to have a bunch of NULLs in the "optional" part of the table, but that should not be your first choice. You may be interested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12321323/533120).

Answer (score 0):

It is more of how the object model looks like based on the features and its properties. if you  dont think of combining multiple attributes to a single feature/element then you can go ahead with one table. otherwise it's better to break it into multiple.

Do u see CDPlayer or Sunroof will have it's own multiple properties ? otherwise you can have this single attribute as a part of the same main table