# Best practice for tables in One-to-one relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

What's the best practice for a scenario where, if you dont split data up into multiple tables, you'll end up with a table consisting of more than 100 columns? The data is of the one-to-one relation.

Comment: If you have 100 columns that describe an entity, then put them in a single table.  Seems unlikely for a normalized data structure, but quite possible for some types of tables.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/12318870/1048425 Essentially, it depends on your exact situation.

Comment: It's basically info about a vehicle, then vehicle is transporing different types of cargo, it has departuring times, arrival times etc. So I guess the best way would be to divide that info into different tables, then.