# access OneToOne relationships and pass to template in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to access oneToOne relationship, but didn't work for me.

according to this documentation 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

```
A Restaurant can access its place:

>>> r.place
<Place: Demon Dogs the place>
A Place can access its restaurant, if available:

>>> p1.restaurant
<Restaurant: Demon Dogs the restaurant>
```

here my `model.py`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    idemp = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class EmployeeDetail(models.Model):
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    employee = models.OneToOneField(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,)
```

here my `view.py`

```
class EmployeeListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'employees'
    model = models.Employee
```

and here my `employee_list.html`

```
{% for employee in employees %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ employee.idemp }}</td>
        <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ employee.nationality }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

run it and result only show `idemp` and `name`.

did I miss something?...

also

I do separate table into 2 table for `employee` and `employe details` since I have access the data and will only show 4 column for the list of employee, and other ( details ) will access all column.

which is better?...

`1. use one table for many columns`

or

`2. split the table into 2 or more for many columns` ( like my case I split `employee` and `employeedetails` )

please explain with `why` and `because`, my brain little bit slow.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access reverse `OneToOne` field with `modelname` attribute, `employeedetail` in your case. To get `nationality` you need to do `employee.employeedetail.nationality`. Try this:

```
{% for employee in employees %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ employee.idemp }}</td>
        <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ employee.employeedetail.nationality }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks its work, can you suggest me `better use separate table, or make it one table` for many columns model?...

Comment: @DickyRaambo it depends. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318870/when-i-should-use-one-to-one-relationship