# Spouse relationship with join table in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, typescript, sequelize.js

Trying to model a spouse relationship similar to the join table option from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4378624 using [Sequelize Typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript).

It kind of works, but doesn't seem very nice. In order to find whether a person is in a marriage, it looks like I have to join on both `person1Id` and `person2Id` in the table (in my example, having `@HasOne` defined twice in the `Person` model).

```js
// Marriage Model
@Column
person1Id: number;
@BelongsTo(() => Person, { foreignKey: { allowNull: false, name: 'person1Id' }, onUpdate: 'CASCADE', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
person1: Person;

@Column
person2Id: number;
@BelongsTo(() => Person, { foreignKey: { allowNull: false, name: 'person2Id' }, onUpdate: 'CASCADE', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
person2: Person;

// marriage date, other properties, etc.
```

```js
// Person Model
@HasOne(() => Marriage, { foreignKey: 'person1Id' })
marriage1: Marriage;

@HasOne(() => Marriage, { foreignKey: 'person2Id' })
marriage2: Marriage;
// really the person only has one marriage, but needed if `Person.id === Marriage.person2Id`
```

I've tried the following, but doesn't retrieve a marriage if they are `person2Id` in the join table.

```js
// DOES NOT WORK
// Person Model
@HasOne(() => Marriage)
marriage: Marriage;


// Retrieving it somewhere else
somePerson = await Person.findOne<Person>({
    include: [
        {
            model: Marriage,
            as: 'marriage'
        }
    ], where: { id: personId }
});

// somePerson.marriage is `undefined` if `Person.id === Marriage.person2Id`!
```

Any ideas on how to make this nicer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I offer implement it just by Using a Foreign Key, maybe meriage model will not be used at all.
some examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one)

Comment: I know there is multiple options (see point 5 of the link you posted) and also the different options from the linked stack overflow question. However, this doesn't answer the question. Maybe you could have posted it as a comment.